# Request succeeds with `request` but fails with `axios`

Tags: node.js, axios, microsoft-graph-api, node-request

I have this microsoft graph authentication code, making what I think is the same request using `axios` and then using `request`. However, the axios request fails with 404, whereas the request request succeeds. What am I doing wrong with axios?

```js
const axios = require('axios')
const request = require("request");
const FormData = require('form-data');

const data = FormData()
data.append('client_id', XXXXXXXXXXX),
data.append('client_secret', XXXXXXXXX),
data.append('scope', "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"),
data.append('grant_type', 'client_credentials')

const requestParams = {
    client_id: logins.activedirectory.clientID,
    client_secret: logins.activedirectory.clientSecret,
    scope: "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
    grant_type: "client_credentials",
};

const endpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + XXXXXXXX + "/oauth2/v2.0/token";

///////// AXIOS //////////
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: endpoint,
    data: data,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
})
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});

///////// REQUEST /////////
request.post({ url:endpoint, form: requestParams }, function (err, response, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(body);
    }
});
```

Comment: It might help if you logged the error instead of just logging "error"

Comment: @Deadron I mean that request is succeeding, it's the axios one that fails

Comment: If you are getting a 404 with the same url and method then the likely culprit is the content type header.

Comment: Try `axios.post(endpoint, data, { headers: data.getHeaders() }).then...`?

Comment: Did you ever solve this. I have the same problem that Axios does not work, but Request works fine. Obviously Axios is not crafting the body correctly for the API, but how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I had a similar issue recently and solved it after a little research. The client credentials API needs a url_encoded body.
This is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service.
The `form-data` package does not does this exactly right. Instead you need to build your body as an object and then stringify and url-encode it. Before and after looks like this:

```
const postData = {
  tenant: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  client_id: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  scope: "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
  client_secret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  grant_type: "client_credentials",
};
```

and stringifed and urlencoded

```
tenant=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

The qs package does this easily. Ref this article https://askfiqri.com/how-to-get-an-access-token-for-microsoft-graph-api-using-node-js-258723f29cc6

The full solution is:

```
    const axios = require("axios");
    const qs = require("qs");
    
    const postData = {
      tenant: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      client_id: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      scope: "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
      client_secret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      grant_type: "client_credentials",
    };
    
   const OAUTH_URL = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${postData.tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token`;
   let response = await axios({
        method: "post",
        url: OAUTH_URL,
        data: qs.stringify(postData),
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
   });
```

then do what you like with response

NOTE: This api call MUST be done from a server or via a proxy (in my case an AWS Lambda via an APIGateway). The axios call will not work from a browser due to CORS errors, that apparently cannot be circumvented.